# Flutter/flutter_facebook_login: unable to see error detail

Tags: flutter, flutter-facebook-login

I have used https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/  inside my Flutter app for Facebook login. The execution keep hitting `FacebookLoginStatus.error` switch.

How can I see more detail of my error?

```
colChildren.add(FacebookSignInButton(onPressed: () async {
  final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
  await facebookLogin.logOut();
  final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);

  switch (result.status) {
    case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
      var token = result.accessToken.token;
      final graphResponse = await http.get(
          'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=${token}');
      final profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);

      print("----> profile");
      print(profile);
      break;
    case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
      break;
    case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
      print ("---> error");
      break;
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Try and ctach(e) to see the error :)

follow this link to know more about Try and ctach(e)

https://flutterrdart.com/dart-exception-handling-with-examples/